# Alfresco Share File upload filter

Tags: file-upload, filter, yui, alfresco, alfresco-share

My file upload filter does not work with Alfresco YUI (or flash?) upload.
I have the following piece of code:

```
        if (null == this.fileUpload) {
            this.fileUpload = Alfresco.getFileUploadInstance();
        }
        var filter = new Array({description:"Images", extensions:"*.jpg;*.png;*.gif"});
        var uploadConfig = {
            mode: this.fileUpload.MODE_SINGLE_UPLOAD
            , username: Alfresco.constants.USERNAME
            , siteId: Alfresco.constants.SITE
            , uploadDirectory: '/'
            , containerId: 'Logo'
            , filter: filter
            , onFileUploadComplete: {
                fn: this.onFileUploadComplete
                , scope: this
            }
        };
        this.fileUpload.show(uploadConfig);
```

This is all cool and upload of files work. I can upload files and there are no issues. But the problem is that the filter does not. What am I missing in this config?

I'm working with Alfresco Share Community version 4.2c.

Comment: Do you know which uploader is used? flash, dnd (drag n drop for html5 browser), or standard html? From the source code (html-upload.js, flash-upload.js, dnd-upload.js) it looks like the filter is not implemented in all of them.

Comment: The filter definition is correct, it must be something else.

Comment: Yep, I thought so too, but I can't find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zladuric,

I believe the filters have to be defined individually. The following worked for me:

```
this.fileUpload = Alfresco.getFileUploadInstance();
var description = "Images";
var extensions = ["*.jpeg", "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif"];
var filter = new Array(
    {description: description, extensions: extensions[0]},
    {description: description, extensions: extensions[1]},
    {description: description, extensions: extensions[2]},
    {description: description, extensions: extensions[3]}
);
var uploadConfig = {...};
this.fileUpload.show(uploadConfig);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, so each filter entry is only one extension? Thanks, I'll try.